# How to read db value in js

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

How do I read db value from my js script?
1) 
I have the following line of codes i want to modify to read value from db table

```
var admin_status=document.form1.admin_status.value;
if(admin_status == 0 && document.form1.ecurr_amount.value>20) 
{
document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML='Please Verify Your Account to process.';  
return false;
}
```

and this :

```
<input type="hidden" name="admin_status" id="admin_status" 
value="<?php echo $obj_db->
fetch_field("select status from tbl_verification_docs where 
userid = '".$_SESSION['user_user']['id']."'")?>" />
```

I use these lines to validate a form -- > to fix a minimum value

a) i want the validation to be from a value hosted in a data (because i want to control that value from admin panel not from script)

right now i have

```
"if(admin_status == 0 && document.form1.ecurr_amount.value>20)"
```

if i want o change that value i need to change the script --> how i want it now is to read that "20" from the entry in a data base

```
if($data_logged_user['admin_status']=='0' && $data_nbtrans_user['COUNT(*)'] > 5 ) 
{
if($data_nbtrans_user['COUNT(*)'] > 5) 
{
echo "Sorry you have reach your max number of transaction for the day, 
come back tomorrow or <a href='http://e-dollar.ng/new-portal/members/accountverification'>
Click here</a> to Verify your Account Now.";
}

}
else 
{
my form goes here..
}
```

b) here i control the number of transactions (it is set to >5)

i want that "5" to be read from a data value instead

i have my db table "tbl_settings"

That's my tbl_settings  how it looks like (from the my db)

```
Setting          Value   type
SITE_STATUS     |  1   | enum
MAX_AMOUNT      |  20  | integer
MAX_TRANSACTION |  5   | integer
```

Comment: You cannot connect JavaScript directly to your database, you need to use PHP to do this.

Comment: If you want to do this without reloading the page, you need to make an AJAX call to PHP. PHP reads the DB, and sends the data back to Javascript.

Comment: yeah thanks, barmar, that's exactly what i want to accomplish but i 
i don't know much how (a little help - example code to guide me is much welcome)

Answer (score 0):

This is the bare bones of a AJAX call but I suggest looking into it a bit more thoroughly.

So in the myAjax function you set ajaxURL to the PHP file that is going to make the database call. Values are passed to the PHP file in the URL, notice value1 is passed to the myAjax function? Well you can add all the values you need this way.

The PHP file should output via an echo a text result based on the database call.

This echo is accessible via http.responseText in Javascript.

```
function myAjax(value1) {

var http = getHTTPObject();
var ajaxUrl ="theUrl.php?";
http.open("GET", ajaxUrl  + "value1=" + value1, false);
http.send(null);  

alert(http.responseText);


}



function getHTTPObject() {
    var xmlhttp;
    /*@cc_on
    @if (@_jscript_version >= 5)
    try {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
      try {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (E) {
        xmlhttp = false;
      }
    }
  @else
  xmlhttp = false;
  @end @*/
    if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
        try 
        {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e) {
        xmlhttp = false;
        }
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}
```